# angularjs ngrepeat setting array value not working

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have an angularjs page which has an ng-repeat <ul> list of data points. Each <li> has a Delete link (call this Delete 1) which when clicked needs to hide that Delete 1 link and show 2 more links in its place: Cancel and Delete (call this Delete 2). When the Cancel link is clicked, the original Delete 1 link needs to show and the Cancel and Delete 2 links need to hide. All this currently works, but now there is a new requirement.

When Delete 1 link is clicked all "Cancel and Delete 2" link pairs on other list items need to hide. As AngularJS is single action based, I create a function for deleteLinkClick and cancelLinkClick to make the required complex actions.

When you look at the controller code provided below you see the show flag being set to false, but it does not work. Suggestions?

Here is my (slim) html page:

```
... OTHER STUFF...
    ul
      li.address ng-repeat="data in request.theData" ng-init="showWarning=[]"
        .address-li
          .address-details
            p
              |Field 1: {{data.field1}}
              span ng-if="data.field2!=''"
                br
                |Field 2: {{data.field2}}
            span
              span.button-small.button-cancel ng-show="!showWarning[$index]" ng-click="deleteLinkClick(showWarning,$index)" Delete
              span.button-small.button-cancel ng-show="showWarning[$index]" ng-click="cancelLinkClick(showWarning,$index)" Cancel
              span.button-small.button-delete.button-warn ng-show="showWarning[$index]" ng-click="deleteAddress($index)" Delete

... OTHER STUFF...
```

Here is my (coffeescript) controller code:

```
@MyPage.controller('MyController',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'NtdRequest', 'Form', '$anchorScroll'
    ($scope, $rootScope, $location, ntd_request, form, $anchorScroll) ->
      $scope.currentIndex = -1

      $scope.cancelLinkClick = (array,index) ->
        array[index] = false
        $scope.currentIndex = -1

      $scope.deleteLinkClick = (array,index) ->
        if ($scope.currentIndex != -1)
          array[$scope.currentIndex] = false
        array[index] = true
        $scope.currentIndex = index
  ]
)
```

Thank you in advance

-wh

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a more angular solution. I hope this is helpful.

First define an appropriate model:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
     app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
         $scope.model = {};
         $scope.model.data = [];
         $scope.model.data.push({ name: 'item1' });
         $scope.model.data.push({ name: 'item2' });
         $scope.model.data.push({ name: 'item3' });
         $scope.model.data.push({ name: 'item4' });
         $scope.model.selected = {};

         $scope.reallyDelete = function(item) {
             alert('Really delete item ' + item.name);
             $scope.model.selected = {};
         }

     });
```

We have defined a model that keeps track of the selected item, and an array of available items.

We have also defined a function called `reallyDelete` which is called from the UI when the second Delete link is clicked.

Here is the View:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in model.data">
            <td> {{item.name }}</td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-hide="model.selected == item" 
                       ng-click="model.selected=item;">Delete</a>
                <span ng-show="model.selected == item">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="reallyDelete(item)">Delete</a>&nbsp;
                    <a href="#" ng-click="model.selected={};">Cancel</a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

We show the first Delete link by binding ng-hide to the `model.selected == item` expression so that the link is hidden when the selected item is the current item.

We show the second pair of links (Delete and Cancel) by binding ng-show to the expression `model.selected==item` so that the links are visible when the selected item is the current item.

When the Cancel link is clicked, we set the selected item to {} so that all links for each item show the unselected state (showing only the Cancel link).

Finally, we bind ng-click for the Delete link to the `reallyDelete` function which is defined on scope.  After the delete is successful, we reset the selected item so that all links for each item show the unselected state again.

By using a simplified model, and taking advantage of angular binding expressions, it is possible to achieve fairly complex behavior.

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ege99jC9OLpKSRF0TQb?p=preview)